# Use nmcli to display the status of a connection

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I'm wondering how to display a connection status using [`nmcli`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli). I understand that the following will display a list of configured connections:

```
nmcli con show
```

And I also understand that the following will show only active connections:

```
nmcli con show --active
```

And that the following will display *all* settings for a connection (which is a very long list):

```
nmcli con show {connection_name}
```

My question is: Is there a quick way to display the status of a connection? Something similar to:

```
nmcli con status {connection_name}
```

Noting that the above is actually *not* a valid option on CentOS or Fedora.

Comment: Did you look at the `--fields` option? Something like `nmcli -f field_name con show {connection_name}`. If you give an invalid value for `field_name` some versions will print all valid field names. Depending on what you get you can possibly further refine by piping through `grep` or `sed` or the like.

Comment: @B Layer Tried that but the --fields option only prints specific columns in the output, so if the argument     --f ACTIVE is given, for example, and there are two active connections, it will print yes yes on two separate lines. That is it.

Comment: What do you want it to print in that case? It might be a good idea to put an example of the output you want in your question. BTW, did you try exactly what I metioned? `nmcli -f {field_name} con show {connection_name}`? And did try the other suggestion where you give an invalid field name?

Answer (score 17):

As user [B Layer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/213782/b-layer) suggested in their comment, you can specify a field name with `nmcli`.

I think the most relevant field in your case is `GENERAL.STATE`:

```
nmcli -f GENERAL.STATE con show {connection_name}
```

For my current connection, this yields:

> GENERAL.STATE:                          activated

Answer (score 3):

If you need a true/false state, you could use nmcli's **-g** option in combination with grep's **-q** as follows:

```
nmcli -g GENERAL.STATE c s interface|grep -q -E '\bactiv'
```

Note the lack of *e* at the end of the word active. It is meant for future proofing if the word *activated* changes to for example *active* or *activity* or some other form at some point.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I adapted it slightly with `grep -q -E '\bactiv'` to make sure it doesn't match when nmcli might decide to print `deactived` if it's down ;-)

Comment: @xpac inactive connections would return nothing, at least on my PC.